# Make only specific symbols in a module importable, f.i. with `__all__`

Tags: python, python-import

#### tl;dr:

I like clean APIs, thus I don't like having "internal" imports, like `import numpy as np` inside of my modules, show up in the module API.

In my package (installable with setup.py) I have several sub-modules, of which each imports a set of modules, f.i. `numpy` or builtins like `sys`.
Let's say in my package `mytools` I have a submodule `mytools.mysubtools` in which I define a function `foo`, which requires `numpy` (imported with `import numpy as np`). `foo` is added to `__all__ = ['foo']` .
Now I import this submodule with `import mytools.mysubtools as mst`. When accessing `mst` with code-completition (for example with Spyder IDE, PyCharm, Kite...) etc., it always shows **all** symbols **and** imports in `mst`, in this case `foo` and `np`.
Can I avoid having imports like `np` show up in the imported module, so that only `foo` shows up?

#### detailed description

Let's say my package structure looks like this:

```
/mytools/
 |-- __init__.py  # "mytools-init"
 |-- my_subtools.py
 |-- some_other_subtools.py
```

The `__init__.py` file looks like this:

```
from . import my_subtools as mysubtools
__all__ = ['mysubtools']
```

And `my_subtools.py`:

```
import numpy as np

__all__ = ['foo']

def foo():
    return np.sqrt(4**3)
```

Now I import `my_subtools` with

```
import mytools.mysubtools as mst
```

When using the imported module, code completition etc. always shows `np` and `foo`, f.i. when typing `mst.`. For larger modules, with many imports and/or function/class definitions, this makes it really hard to use code completition, since a simple inspection of the API shows **all** imported modules and all definitions.

With `__all__` it is possible to avoid importing all symbols for wild/star imports, like `from mytools.mysubtools import *`. Can `__all__` somehow also be used to mangle explicit imports?

Or is there any recommended way to avoid importing all symbols of a module?
For functions, I use **name mangling**, f.i. `def _baz(): return 4**4`.
But is this also **advisable for imports**, f.i. `import numpy as _np`? Any downsides?

What I'm looking for:
An explicit solution, since: *Explicit is better than implicit.*
For example something like `__all__`, but for explicit imports. Or something like `__except__ = ['np']` which excludes symbols from imports.

Comment: "When accessing ``mst`` with code-completition etc., it always shows all symbols and imports in mst, in this case foo and np." Python itself does not have code completion. What is "it"?

Comment: You are right. I was of course speaking of code completion of editors like Spyder, PyCharm etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of @chepner, I've been looking into the linked implementation in the python standard library.

The conclusion is, that **name mangling of imported modules** is used **frequently** in the standard library. This is in my opinion a quite clear sign, that this is considered pythonic and/or has no severe downsides.
Several examples of name-mangling imports can be found, f.i.:

- [random.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/14d5331eb5e6c38be12bad421bd59ad0fac9e448/Lib/random.py)
- [string.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/14d5331eb5e6c38be12bad421bd59ad0fac9e448/Lib/string.py)
- [_pydecimal.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/14d5331eb5e6c38be12bad421bd59ad0fac9e448/Lib/_pydecimal.py)

Which modules are name-mangled seems to change from file to file. It seems that the more "system-relevant" the module is, the less likely it is to be name mangled. For example imports like

```
import re as _re
import math as _math
```

are frequently name mangled, while `import os as _os` is less commong. This is a merely my impression, so it may not be true in general.

Answer (score 1):

`__all__ = [...]` is a good hint of the "exportable" names, but it's just a hint. (Some IDEs such as PyCharm do tend to get the clue though.)

I definitely wouldn't do `import numpy as _np`; you'd just be making your life harder.

You can't prevent someone from importing things from your module, if they're there... and if you really *really* wanted to, you of course could postfix all of your modules with mantras like `del np, sys, os, quux, bar`; that way those names wouldn't be importable, but... I really don't think it's worth the effort.

Comment: It's more than a hint. It defines what `from foo import *` means. Also, `import foo as _foo` is a common idiom, used in the standard library itself (e.g., https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/14d5331eb5e6c38be12bad421bd59ad0fac9e448/Lib/threading.py)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was hoping for some explicit style like an `__all__` specific for explicit imports or a *reverse*-`__all__` like `__except__ = ['np']` which excludes symbols from imports...

Comment: @chepner So you'd say that name mangled imports are good to use?

Comment: The [documentation for `import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=__all__#the-import-statement) discusses the semantics of `__all__`. It explicitly mentions that `_`-prefixed names are *not* included in the public interface of a module when `__all__` is not defined (and of course when `__all__` *is* defined, nothing is implicitly part of the public interface).

Comment: Thanks! Reading the line "It is intended to avoid accidentally exporting items that are not part of the API (such as library modules which were imported and used within the module)." in the documentation it feels like they implicitly encourage the user to also use name-mangling on imports (at least from an integral perspective on the API)...